# Forming error messages from a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, array, iteration

I'm working with an input array, which is 3 levels deep, and creating error message strings accordingly in a separate output array.  Below is the code.

```
$e['invalid']['key'][] = 'a123';
$e['invalid']['key'][] = 'a456';
$e['invalid']['color'][] = 'red';
$e['missing']['key'][] = 'b72';
$e['missing']['color'][] = 'blue';
$e['missing']['color'][] = 'green';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($e, 1) . '</pre>';


function generateErrorMessages($e)
{
    $errors;
    foreach ($e as $type => $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $values)
        {               
            foreach ($values as $v)
            {
                switch($type)
                {
                    case 'invalid':
                                    $errors[$type][$key][] = $v . ' is not a valid ' . $key;
                                    break;
                    case 'missing':
                                    $errors[$type][$key][] = $v . ' is a required ' . $key . ' - other functions have dependencies on it';
                                    break;
                    default:        
                                    // do nothing                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

$msgs = generateErrorMessages($e);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($msgs, 1) . '</pre>';
```

While this achieves the desired outcome, the nested `foreach` loops in the `generateErrorMessages()` method seem onerous and difficult to read.  Is there a more concise way to generate the error messages?

Here is a screenshot of the input array:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the output array:
[image]

Comment: How do you define "difficult to read"? As any explicit code, all these loops are quite straightforward to follow. And making it more concise will likely make it more cryptic as well

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking into JSON.

Comment: @Andrew what exactly would be the benefit of looking into JSON?

Comment: @mickmackusa Lots of key->value (mapped) string data, several layers deep: storing and using it as JSON would be ideal. You also then get tons of JSON library support which will help you to parse through the collection easily and intuitively. There's lots of support for e.g. (language) object <-> string JSON manipulation too, and you could use just 100% the object side if wanted. It doesn't directly address the OP's multi-loop problem, but it might help if nothing else.

Comment: Also, with something like JSON, you might be able to more easily create functions that loop through pieces of the collection generically, and then you could reuse these functions without having to manually go several layers deep.

Comment: Nope... I still don't see the benefit here. @Andrew

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, this code is all right.  As any explicit code, these loops are quite straightforward to follow. And making it more concise will likely make it more cryptic as well. I would only make a minor brush-up, removing the unnecessary default clause and make the proper indentation. Variable interpolation is also more natural to read, in my opinion.

Also, variables must be explicitly initialized, just a mention is not enough. If you need an empty array then you must initialize an empty array. Although in the present code the `$errors` variable doesn't exist before the loop, the code could evolve over time, and there could be the possibility that a variable with the same name will be used above. If you just mention it, as `$errors;` it will keep the previous value. If you initialize it as `$errors = [];` you will always know it's an empty array.

```
function generateErrorMessages($e)
{
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($e as $type => $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $values)
        {               
            foreach ($values as $v)
            {
                switch($type)
                {
                    case 'invalid':
                        $errors[$type][$key][] = "$v is not a valid $key";
                        break;
                    case 'missing':
                        $errors[$type][$key][] = "$v is a required $key - other functions have dependencies on it";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Can you expound on the comment that variables must be explicitly initialized?

Comment: That's simple. If you need an empty array then you must initialize an empty array. Although in the present code the $errors variable doesn't exist before the loop, the code could evolve over time, and there could be the possibility that an array with the same name will have some contents. If you just mention it, as `$errors;` it will keep the previous value. If you initialize it as `$errors = [];` you wull always know it's an empty array.

Comment: Can you edit that into your answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with what "Your Common Sense" said, but I would like to have better variable names. Names that make clear what a variable contains. Seen in isolation variable names like `$e`, `$array` and `$v` don't really convey what they contain. Abbreviated variable names don't make your code easier to read. Also `$errors` does contain errors, but more precisely it contains error messages. So, I would write this as:

```
function convertToErrorMessages($errors)
{
    $errorMessages = [];
    foreach ($errors as $errorType => $error)
    {
        foreach ($error as $property => $values)
        {   
            $valueMessages = [];            
            foreach ($values as $value)
            {
                switch($errorType)
                {
                    case 'invalid':
                        $valueMessages[] = "$value is not a valid $property";
                        break;
                    case 'missing':
                        $valueMessages[] = "$value is a required $property".
                                           " - other functions have dependencies on it";
                        break;
                }
            }
            $errorMessages[$errorType][$property] = $valueMessages;
        }
    }
    return $errorMessages;
}
```

Note that I also collect all the value messages before assigning them to the error messages array. This prevents code repetition, especially when you have many error types. I also don't like long long lines, so I split those.

One thing I sometimes do when there are many nested braces, is leaving out braces that will never be useful. Like this:

```
function convertToErrorMessages($errors)
{
    $errorMessages = [];
    foreach ($errors as $errorType => $error)
    foreach ($error as $property => $values)
    {   
        $valueMessages = [];            
        foreach ($values as $value)
        switch($errorType)
        {
            case 'invalid':
                $valueMessages[] = "$value is not a valid $property";
                break;
            case 'missing':
                $valueMessages[] = "$value is a required $property".
                                   " - other functions have dependencies on it";
                break;
        }
        $errorMessages[$errorType][$property] = $valueMessages;
    }
    return $errorMessages;
}
```

This might not be to everyones liking, but I think it is acceptable or even slightly easier to read.

I also had a look as "mickmackusa" solution. A lookup array can make sense, for instance when you're using multiple languages. Also, the idea to separate the configuration from the processor code is a valid one, but for now it only seems to complicate the code (PS: mickmackusa updated his answer and it looks a lot better now).

Comment: In your second example, although I am not a fan of missing out braces just for the sake of it, the lack of indentation of the `switch` makes the code worse IMHO.

Comment: I think this is the purpose of comments. Renaming every variable name to >10 characters makes typing code take much longer on large projects, and in most cases short names work. If not, just use a comment. Typing `errorMessages` each time in a large project would be seriously annoying, especially when something like `eMsgs` or `msgs` would work just as well.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I do understand that long names can require more typing, but for me clarity and readability of code is more important. The worst example I came across recently is the [CAMT.053 file format](https://www.sepaforcorporates.com/swift-for-corporates/a-practical-guide-to-the-bank-statement-camt-053-format/), they abbreviate everything. Things like `CdtDbtInd`, `AddtlInfInd`, `PmtInfId`, `RltdPties` and so on. My point is: It might be clear to the author what these cryptic things mean, to someone new to the code they're not.

Comment: @redwolf programs long variable bames shouldnt bother you. You should use some IDE And IDEs Will autocomplete the name after you type few chars. Readability should be prefered.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That's why I mentioned comments. `$AddtlInfInd; //Addition Info Indicator` would be better IMO than `$additionalInfoIndicator`

Comment: @slepic I use a text editor, not an IDE, like many people. And, with a comment and some easily guessable abbreviations, it's still just as readable. In my opinion, long variable names are _less_ readable, since I have to read the whole thing instead of a 3-5 character abbreviation whose purpose I already know/read in a previous comment. Especially in something like this question with only a few variables and a clear purpose for the function, short but still readable (`err`, `msg`, `data`, `i`, `eMsg`, etc.) variable names make the function seem more readable to me since it's shorter.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms comments get outdated, variables dont. If you wanna write programs like a professional, you should use an IDE. The purpose of abbreviated name is clear to you - the author of the code, but you can be sure it won't always be clear to someone else who is seeing the code for the first time. In fact it may not be clear even to you if you leave that code for some time and come back to it months later. If you are writing code for yourself, do whatever you want if you find it better. But if you hope your code is going to be read by others one day, use long names with clear meaning.

Comment: @slepic Comments don't become outdated if they only contain a variable's name, and most people are going to realize the meaning of `err`, `msg`, `arr`, etc.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms As i said, do what you want with your code. If you find it better. It's your problem. But believe me, once your commits need to be approved by someone else (opensource project maintaner, your senior collegue, etc..) before they are accepted, you will very likely be asked to improve the variable names otherwise your changes will be rejected... Btw i realize meaning of `err` and `msg` but i have no idea what `arr` is...

Comment: @slepic `arr` is short for `array`. That's pretty widely used, at least in JS

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms lol, of course. But array is the type of the variable, not its meaning.

Comment: @slepic In a function which converts an array into a string, `arr` would be a perfectly acceptable variable name

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Not if I'm reviewing your code :) Howgh. Good bye.

Answer (score 6):

Before I get started with the script polishing, I just want to voice that I don't think it makes sense to bloat/hydrate your otherwise lean data storage with redundant text.  If you are planning on presenting this to the end user as a means to communicate on a "human-friendly" level, then abandon the array-like structure and write plain English sentences.

How can you make your code more manageable? I recommend a lookup array.  This will allow you to separate your "processing" code from your "config" code.  The processing part will be built "generally" so that it will appropriately handle incoming data based on the "specific" data in the lookup array.

By declaring the lookup as a constant (because it won't vary -- it doesn't need to be a variable), the lookup will enjoy a global scope.  This will benefit you if plan to write a custom function to encapsulate the processing code.  IOW, you won't need to pass the lookup into your function as an argument or use [shiver] `global`.

Now whenever you want to extend your error array-hydrating function to accommodate new `types`, **you ONLY need to add a single line of code to the lookup** (`ERROR_LOOKUP`) -- you never need to touch the processor.  In contrast, a `switch` block will require 3 new lines of code for each new allowance. This makes scaling your script much easier, cleaner, and more concise.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vr83e))

```
define("ERROR_LOOKUP", [
    'invalid' => '%s is not a valid %s',
    'missing' => '%s is a required %s - other functions have dependencies on it',
]);

$errors = [];
foreach ($e as $type => $subtypes) {
    if (!isset(ERROR_LOOKUP[$type])) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($subtypes as $subtype => $entry) {               
        foreach ($entry as $string) {
            $errors[] = sprintf(ERROR_LOOKUP[$type], $subtype, $string);
        }
    }
}
echo implode("\n", $errors);
```

Output:

```
a123 is not a valid key
a456 is not a valid key
red is not a valid color
b72 is a required key - other functions have dependencies on it
blue is a required color - other functions have dependencies on it
green is a required color - other functions have dependencies on it
```

Your output strings may have static text on either/both sides of the `$subtype` value, so `sprintf()` makes the variable insertion very clean and flexible. Credit to @NigelRen for suggesting this improvement to my snippet.

The `continue` in the outermost loop ensures that no wasted iteration occurs on deadend array data.  No "do nothing" outcomes on inner loops. Alternatively, you could use `array_intersect_key()` to replace the conditional `continue` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pe4G9)).

p.s. I have a deep-seated hatred for `switch` block syntax with so many `break` lines.  This is why I often replace them with lookup arrays.

p.p.s. If you are writing an OOP structured script/project, see @slepic's post.

Comment: Well if it's supposed to be returned in response to AJAX call, "littering" seems to be quite a standard approach

Comment: I don't see anything to suggest that the OP is generating an AJAX response.

Comment: @mickmackusa This is an awesome way to replace the `switch` statement! Prior to using the `switch` block I had experimented with using `$message['invalid'] = $v . ' is not a valid ' . $key;  $message['missing'] = $v . ' is a required ' . $key . ' - other functions have dependencies on it';  $errors[$type][$key][] = $message[$type];` in the innermost `foreach` loop. I abandoned that because it didn't seem right to create the `$messages` array for every single pass through the loop.  Your solution rectifies that issue AND the lookup's values are strings instead of variables. Utterly brilliant!

Comment: Yet you accept another review? Okay.

Comment: Only because the other one directly addressed the original question about the nested `foreach` loops. The intention originally was to try and find a more concise way to achieve the outcome without that approach.  I had wondered about `array_walk` and `array_map` but neither of those were suggested.  Your response about replacing the `switch` was a bonus.

Comment: I am focussing on this quote from your question: _Is there a more concise way to generate the error messages?_  I say, Yes, and I have shown how to make your script scalable.  No worries, I'm not going to get hostile about it.

Comment: Replacing a switch by an array is a good idea in some cases, and in some cases it is not. In the OP's case, it should be good as long as all the messages contain two `%s`s in appropriate order. BUT putting the stuff in global constants is a terrible idea. The data and the behaviour can and should be encapsulated in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered. But what I am showing here is just response to mickmackusa's answer, which OP called a "bonus". And so let OP and everyone wandering here in future can see one possible way to avoid spoiling global scope with constants as shown in mickmackusa's answer. The code below is his solution encapsulated in a static class:

```
final class ErrorMessagesConverter
{
  private static $lookupTable = [
    'invalid' => '%s is not a valid %s',
    'missing' => '%s is a required %s - other functions have dependencies on it',
  ];

  private function __construct() {};

  public static function convert(iterable $input): array
  {
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($input as $type => $subtypes) {
        if (!\array_key_exists($type, self::lookupTable)) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($subtypes as $subtype => $entry) {               
            foreach ($entry as $string) {
                $errors[] = sprintf(self::lookupTable[$type], $subtype, $string);
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
  }
}
```

Shall I add that every `$subtypes` and `$entry` should be checked for being iterable before actualy iterating them...

Comment: Fair enough.  If the OP would have made any indication that their script/project was OOP designed, I may have suggested a class too.  In my opinion `isset()` is more ideal for the continue check because 1. it is slightly faster and 2. it will `continue` if an existing key's value is `null` (`null` is not iterable anyhow).  May I ask why you bothered declaring the empty constructor? (+1) ...p.s. Duh, I don't know why I used `in_array()`, I'm always pushing for key-based lookups -- I'll fix that now with `isset()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa well, it doesnt have to be OOP and yet no global constants involved. That would be a global function with static local variable. Another option would be an instantiable class where you could actualy define the message templates upon construction... But I understand your point... As for isset vs array_key_exists, yeah definitely could be I wasnt really thinking about this. I just replaced in_array to avoid two variables. And as for the private constructor, yeah, definitely not necesary. It's just in those rare cases when I define static class I make sure noone tries instantiate it.